# How can I pull twice in the git?

Tags: git, git-pull

I pulled the project once by this code:

```
$ git pull origin master
```

And I removed the whole project *(except .git directory)* by hand. Now I want to get the project again. When I pull it again, it says:

```
$ git pull origin master
From https://bitbucket.org/path/to/repository
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

And my working directory is still empty *(there is just .git directory)*. Anyway, how can I pull the project again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not pulling that you need.
Pulling is for getting changes from the remote repository to synchronize with your local.
You *can* pull as many times as you want,
but if nothing changed at the remote,
you will just get the message as you did,
that you are already up to date.

You can restore your working directory from the repository with:

```
git checkout .
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks. Just for my information, if I have some changes on the working directory, and run your command, all my change will be lost?

Comment: @MartinAJ To be precise, all *unstaged* changes will be lost.

Answer (score 3):

Just check everything out again

```
git checkout .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do `git checkout`, as *@janos* suggestted in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45252856/4000674).
Another way of doing it is hard reseting to the branch you want:

```
git reset --hard remote/branch
```

The way reseting works is well described in the [Git book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45252856/4000674).